# make a single buffer using memcpy

Tags: c++, memcpy

I am writing a C++ code. here The goal of the program is to create single buffer from two or three different buffers. Here is the code I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    uint8_t LLDP_STANDARD_DST_MAC_STRING [] = {0x01,0x80,0xc2,0x00,0x00,0x0e};
    uint16_t LLDP_EtherType={ 0x88CC};`
    uint8_t* buf=new uint8_t[14];`
    uint8_t LLDP_STANDARD_SRC_MAC_STRING[] = {0x11,0x81,0xC3,0x01,0x01,0x1e};`
    memcpy(buf,&LLDP_STANDARD_DST_MAC_STRING,6);
    memcpy(buf+sizeof(LLDP_STANDARD_DST_MAC_STRING),&LLDP_STANDARD_SRC_MAC_STRING,6);

    std::cout << "first data " << sizeof(buf) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "firt data " << (uint8_t) buf[12] << std::endl;
}
```

When I run the code, size of buf  the code is priting 8. It is wrong?
The value is not clear text. some different charatcter.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards
Sothy

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: `buf` is a pointer `sizeof` a pointer is the size of the pointer on your architecture.

Comment: You have a 64-bit system. The size of a pointer on your system is 8 bytes. Not surprising. The `sizeof` operator clearly doesn't do what you think it does. Time to check the documentation.

Comment: @CodyGray typo 8 bytes ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Richard, got that fix in just in time!

Comment: 8 is the size of the pointer

Comment: My question is that how to find the size of array? array is buf. what function I can use? thanks

Comment: @sothy: Why don't you _read_ the page you were linked to quarter of an hour ago?

Comment: @sothy you created a dynamic array, you either need to: remember the size you created it; or use `std::array`; or use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Richard, I got the point. Now Another question, I try to retrieve the data from buf. Data seems not understandable buf[0] is ok for retrieving the data from buf? which cast I have to use?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask in a new question.